# Which one scales better? ORM's distinct() or python set()

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

and happy new year!

I have a model which will hold some hundreds of thousands of records. The model looks like this:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    amount = models.FloatField()
```

I want to know all clients a certain user is dealing with. To get the unique client ids, I could use the Django ORM alone:

```
Transaction.objects.filter(user=the_user).distinct('client_id').values_list('client_id', flat=True)
```

or do the following:

```
set(Transaction.objects.filter(user=the_user).values_list('client_id', flat=True))
```

Both will produce the same result. But which one will be quicker given the large set of records? I know `distinct` is a relatively slow operation on databases, but how it compares to python's `set()`?

Finally, if it goes down to databases, my options are MySql and PostgreSql for production. Would there be any difference between the two of them for this specific operation?

Comment: I hope you aren't actually using a float for storing currency amounts.

Comment: Ok, let's say I'll use Decimal, it's just a quick example! :)

Comment: I would hope that `.distinct` relies on the implementation of the RDBMS which might be much faster than Python's `set` for uniqueness. A better question would be: "I've measured the timings using timeit, and got the following results: blah, bleh, blih. Why is blah faster than bleh, given that I've seen at bluh that bloh.", as a template-example.

Comment: I'm a bit disturbed that you believe that DISTINCT is slower on a database than on Python. Is this a common belief? Do people have some rationale for this?

Comment: I don't believe anything, in fact I didn't know and that's why I asked in the first place! I read distinct is a relatively slow operation and I wanted people to enlighten me on this, I don't see how this could disturb someone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually use the orm functions, it's more readable and it runs on database level, so is your RDBMS who actually computes the distinct values, and you have your result in a single step.

You can accomplish the same with a python set, but you need to first bring all your data set, and then apply a set(). So you have to perform a two step operation to do the same.

In your first case (orm) you only have the I/O overhead, and in the second case, you have the I/O overhead + a function call, so I would go with the ORM's distinct.

Comment: More importantly, in the second case you need to transfer (potentially significantly) more data from the DB into Python, which increases the I/O overhead. The upside is, of course, the DB being relieved of some work, but hopefully the DB's `distinct` functionality is as efficient as, or more efficient, than Python's `set`.

Comment: interesting insight, the memory trade off is an important factor since the RDBMS will load all records anyway. I'll go with distinct and maybe do a proper benchmarking when I have the time. Thank you all!